# Qt: Assertion Failure error given on a project which was working perfectly

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

I had my project running perfectly. Updated my project on bitbucket [bitbucket.org] and then added some comments. Ran my project again. And strangely, this error given.

```
ASSERT failure in QVector<T>::operator[]: "index out of range", file ..\..\include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qvector.h, line 385
```

I thought I may have messed something up during commenting, so immediately looked for error, found none. Okay, I may have missed something. So, logged in to bitbucket and downloaded the project. Deleted the old project and ran the fresh one. SAME PROBLEM WITH SAME ERROR. Whats the problem? And how can I get such error out of no where?

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //QHBoxLayout *layout=new QHBoxLayout;
    WeekAndDailyView *view=new WeekAndDailyView(this);
    //layout->addWidget(view);
    qDebug()<<"Came here"<<endl;
    setCentralWidget(view);
}
```

Application Output:

```
Came here

ASSERT failure in QVector<T>::operator[]: "index out of range", file ..\..\include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qvector.h, line 385
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
```

And little more strange, my main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    qDebug()<<"Came Here"<<endl;
    w.show();
    qDebug()<<"Came Here"<<endl;
    return a.exec();
}
```

Application Output:

```
Came Here 

ASSERT failure in QVector<T>::operator[]: "index out of range", file ..\..\include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qvector.h, line 385
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
G:\Programming\Projects\QT try\build-CasePage-Desktop_Qt_5_3_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\CasePage.exe exited with code 3
```

Note: I am using Qt 3.1.1 absed on Qt 5.2.1(MSVC 2010, 32 bit) on Windows. I have only one MinGW installed. And I have already restarted the machine and re installed Qt.

Comment: Checkout the edit please

Comment: check what you have changed, you will spot the source of the problem

Comment: There is no obvious QVector in the code you posted.  The advice still stands, run it in the debugger and look at the stack trace when the assert happens then walk back the stack to the code that is causing the out of range access.

Comment: The point is, I have not changed the code. Not a bit. And I think I have mentioned that in my question. I have downloaded the old version of the project which was running perfectly.

Comment: Do you want to keep saying you haven't changed anything, or solve the problem?  You haven't posted enough code for anyone to see the problem and help you, so it seems you need to do some work to track it down.  If you have undefined behavior in your program maybe there's something making it behave differently.  Maybe you changed something else on your computer that is affecting things, we can't know, but you can narrow it down yourself or provide enough information for someone else to help you.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I guess the QVector is in setCentalWidget function which is provided in QMainWindow. Isn't it highly unusual to get error during setting central widget or later? Because that's what qt handles not the programmer.

Comment: Some more info added.

Comment: Did you try to delete your old build directory ?
Sometimes when I compile over an existing build, errors like yours appear out of nowhere. I often resolves those by deleting my build folder, or by using the "Clean All" and "Rebuild All" command in Qt Creator.

Comment: I have got the exact same error with the exact same line number. I made a copy of my project and then changed the name and then ran it and then ever since have got that problem. Have restarted my machine, reinstalled Qt and used the debugger but can't find the issue. I will post on here f I ever find out, thanks!!